# byte & 0xff | Java

Tags: java, byte, bit

I had a look at the Twofish source code in Java and discovered this line, which I don't quite understand.

```java
public static byte[] blockEncrypt (byte[] in, int inOffset, Object sessionKey) {
    int x0 = (in[inOffset++] & 0xFF) | (in[inOffset++] & 0xFF) <<  8 | (in[inOffset++] & 0xFF) << 16 | (in[inOffset++] & 0xFF) << 24;
}
```

Here, a byte is offset with a logical AND with 0xFF (11111111). Why is this done? If I take an 8-bit value and calculate it & (logical AND) 0xFF, the value I had previously is returned in the end, because only the bits that were 1 in the original value are taken over. (11010011 & 11111111 should result in 11010011)

Comment: `0xFF` as byte is `0x000000FF` as an int. If for some reason Java uses ints to calculate, you make sure that other possible bytes in the front are 'cut off'. I am not sure this will have a real effect in the method posted above; simply try it out. But when it comes to byte shifting and masking, lots of unexpected things can happen, especially with the sign bit. When casting a negative `byte` to `int`, will it look like `0b 10000000 00000000 00000000 0xxxxxxx` or like `0b 00000000 00000000 00000000 1xxxxxxx`? Check out the Java Language Specification for more info on those topics.

Comment: According to Java's `Integer.toBinaryString()` `Integer.toBinaryString((byte) 128);` is 11111111111111111111111110000000 and `Integer.toBinaryString((byte)128 & 0xff)` is 10000000. I think you are right and this just ensures that resulting numbers still are "as long as a byte" even they are an integer.

Comment: I think it may have effect if bit 7 of the byte is 1. That is, anything between 0x80 and 0xFF. Without the mask, that bit will be taken as sign and extended to become 0xFFFFFF80-0xFFFFFFFF. With the mask, you get the unsigned integer.

Comment: Right, this is commonly done to treat the byte as an unsigned integer.  Bytes in Java are normally signed.  And-ing the byte with 0xFF sign extends it to an integer but then just grabs the lower 8 bits of the int, resulting in an unsigned value between 0-255.

Comment: You are right. 0xFF will result in 0xFFFFFFFF when converted to integer, 0x7F will result in 0x7F. The use of & 0xFF (0x000000FF) will just cut off all but the last 8 bit.